# failure reading format string off the stack in c

Tags: c, string, security, format

I am learning about format string vulnerabilities and am confused by the behavior of my code. I recognize that I need to know more about how the stack actually works, compiler optimizations, and more, but as of now I don't know and hope to get a useful reply. I have spent many hours trying to figure it out and have some guesses but I really don't know what is happening.

I have the following code:

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<string.h>
    int main(int argc, char** argv){
        char test[1024];
        strcpy(test,argv[1]);
        printf(test);
        //printf(argv[1]); // print without using local variable
    }
```

Assuming a.exe is the compiled code, the following input returns the next line.

`a.exe "AAAA.%08x.%08x.%08x.%08x.%08x"`

My output is: AAAA.b8c1fa30.b8c25940.0061de60.41414141.30252e78

If I uncomment out the next printf(), it appends the same input string

This is what I expected. I can see the AAAA printed as 41414141 and confirm that I am, indeed, looking at my format string using either a local variable or directly as an argument to main().

However, if I comment out the local variable and strcpy() function and only print the argument to main(), then I get the following output.

`AAAA.001a13a0.001a4730.00000011.001a13a0.004013c7  // removed both`

and if I just remove strcpy() and comment out the print statement that uses the local variable then I get this output:

`AAAA.00a813a0.00a84730.00000011.000003ff.00000002 // removed strcpy()`

This confuses me. Why am I not seeing the 41414141 for my string of A's and what are the, presumably integers, of 0x11 and 0x02?? Why don't I ever see 41414141 in my output if I do not have local variables?

I know that I am uninformed about some aspect of stack management but beats the heck out of me if I can figure it out.

Edit: removed superfluous printf statement to appease pedantics

Comment: I think that you don't understand how to use `printf`.  Try replacing your 2 printf calls with this one: `printf("You wrote: %s\n", test);`

Comment: If you are trying to "fish" what is on the stack by passing formatting specs to `printf` from user input, your territory is *undefined behaviour*. No right-minded programmer would let you do that as a user.

Comment: It is a string format vulnerability, often encountered as an unintended bug. This code is standard fare for describing it. My question is on stack behavior, not the programmer's mental stability. :-)

Comment: removed printf("you entered:") from the code to avoid further comments on code style.

Comment: You get different results because the intervening calls which you comment out leave the (now unused part of) the stack in a different state, which you access 'illegally'. Why should it be the same?